# Store incoming data from serial port to text file

Tags: qt, text, read-write

Hi I need to save incoming data from my serial port into a text file.
I only want to record like this output into a file.

I use:

```
QFile file("c://out.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream out(&file);
```

[image]

But I can't save it. Can anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: where is the other part of your code that adds data to the `out` stream?

Comment: What does “I can't save it” means?